# How to print report object name in each report?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I would like how to print report object name into the the title of the form container, or alternatively into the report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a MorphX report you create a [display method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa595058%28v=ax.50%29.aspx) returning [element.name()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa678867%28v=ax.50%29.aspx), then drag the method to the relevant page header.

If you want to do this for most reports, then change the [report template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa661024%28v=ax.50%29.aspx) `InternalList` and `FrontPage`.